# Can't load static files inside Vue.js component

Tags: vue.js

I have component Login.vue and inside its template I paste

```
<img src="logo.png">
```

The catalog structure is the same as here: https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

I got static folder inside src folder.

I try many diffrent combinations like

```
<img src="src/assets/logo.png">
<img src="assets/logo.png">
```

When I try to write with a dot prefix (absolute path)

```
<img src="./src/assets/logo.png">
```

I got and error from babel compiler: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './logo.png'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put those images into `/static` folder and use them as `src="/static/[filename]"` (use absolute path).

Static folder is not processed by webpack.